# How do I setup a Symlink/Clone DNS zone?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Is there any way I can setup BIND with DNS-DLZ to answer xxx.org requests as it were xxx.com zone?
I want to avoid maintaining multiple zones with the exact same data.

Answer (score 6):

As long as the zone contents are identical, just re-use the same zone file.

This obviously means all labels in the zone file must be *relative*, i.e.:

```
relative IN A 1.2.3.4
```

is ok, but

```
absolute.example.com. IN A 1.2.3.4
```

is not.

Comment: Make sure you don't include any `$ORIGIN` lines either, otherwise bind would refuse to load the zone.

Comment: it's grawity! looky that.

Comment: I use MySQL not files (DNS-DLZ) - I also edited the question as I committed to mention it :(

Comment: Thus rendering my advice completely useless and seemingly irrelevant.